# String concatenation inside traversal in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

This is a syntax issue I think; I am trying to add a dynamic element to my traversal (? Might be the wrong word) which adds the text of a number of buttons to a list. This is basically pseudo-code but it is how I am thinking:

```
list = [self.root.ids.('button_' + i).text for i in range (5)]
```

This is to save me having the following:

```
list = []
list.append(self.root.ids.button_1.text)
list.append(self.root.ids.button_2.text)
list.append(self.root.ids.button_3.text)
list.append(self.root.ids.button_4.text)
list.append(self.root.ids.button_5.text)
```

Is it possible to do this? The `button_#` is the bit that should be dynamic. Apologies If any of my terms are incorrect here.

Comment: `getattr(self.root.ids, 'button_%d' % i).text` in case `i` is an integer, if not use `%s`.

Comment: That is exactly right, how can I mark this as the right answer? I'm going to do some reading on getattr() now, thank you.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attributes dynamically, you have to use `getattr(obj, 'attr_name')`.

In your case it could be like this:

```
getattr(self.root.ids, 'button_%d' % i).text
```

For additional details see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).